# React App getting Blank while using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have created a react app I have added code for navbar which uses react-router-dom after running the App went blank without any content , when I openend console I found You need to enable JavaScript to run this app. inside body tag

What should I do to get the actual content loaded.

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import React from "react"
import MainPage from './components/Mainpage'
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <React.Fragment>
          <BrowserRouter>
          <MainPage/>
          </BrowserRouter>
      </React.Fragment>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Mainpage.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import NavPage from './Navpage'

const MainPage = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <section className='md:w-2/5 md:mx-auto'>
        {/* navbar section */}
      <div className="bg-blue-100 h-20 w-full centered">
          <Navbar/>

      </div>

      {/* navPage section */}
      <div className="bg-blue-100 h-screen w-full">
          <NavPage/>

      </div>
    </section>
  </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default MainPage
```

**Navbar.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
  const activeLink = " bg-blue-100 text-black";
  const normalLink = "";

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <section>
        <div className="w-full h-16 bg-black text-white text-xl uppercase font-bold grid grid-cols-4 overflow-hidden">
          <NavLink
            to="/"
            className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? activeLink : normalLink)}
          >
            <p className="border w-full h-full px-4 centered">URL</p>
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/textpage"
            className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? activeLink : normalLink)}
          >
            <p className="border w-full h-full px-4 centered">PlainText</p>
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/phonepage"
            className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? activeLink : normalLink)}
          >
            <p className="border w-full h-full px-4 centered">Phone</p>
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/smspage"
            className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? activeLink : normalLink)}
          >
            <p className="border w-full h-full px-4 centered">SMS</p>
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/mailpage"
            className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? activeLink : normalLink)}
          >
            <p className="border w-full h-full px-4 centered">Mail</p>
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/wifipage"
            className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? activeLink : normalLink)}
          >
            <p className="border w-full h-full px-4 centered">Wifi</p>
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/pdfpage"
            className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? activeLink : normalLink)}
          >
            <p className="border w-full h-full px-4 centered">Pdf</p>
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/imagepage"
            className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? activeLink : normalLink)}
          >
            <p className="border w-full h-full px-4 centered">Image</p>
          </NavLink>
         
        </div>
      </section>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

**Navpage.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Urlpage from '../pages/Urlpage';
import Textpage from '../pages/Textpage';
import Phonepage from '../pages/Phonepage';
import Smspage from '../pages/Smspage';
import Mailpage from '../pages/Mailpage';
import Wifipage from '../pages/Wifipage';
import Pdfpage from '../pages/Pdfpage';
import Imagepage from '../pages/Imagepage';

const NavPage = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <section>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Urlpage />} />
          <Route path="/textpage" element={<Textpage />} />
          <Route path="/phonepage" element={<Phonepage />} />
          <Route path="/smspage" element={<Smspage />} />
          <Route path="/mailpage" element={<Mailpage />} />
          <Route path="/wifipage" element={<Wifipage/>} />
          <Route path="/pdfpage " element={<Pdfpage />} />
          <Route path="/imagepage " element={<Imagepage />} />

        </Routes>
      </section>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default NavPage;
```

Comment: "when I opened console I found 'You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.' inside body tag" - Have you enabled Javascript to run in the browser? Can you [edit] to include your `index.html` and `index.js` files? See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your App only display the content of your `index.html`

To render a React element, first pass the DOM element to `ReactDOM.createRoot()`, then pass the React element to `root.render()`

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root')
);
const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
root.render(element);
```

Follow the official [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#rendering-an-element-into-the-dom) for additional context